# <Link>s rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have three `div` in my `index.html` file as

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="crm"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Now i have `rendered` header content in header, my main content in crm and footer content in footer like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <HF.Header />,
   document.getElementById("header")
);

ReactDOM.render(
   routes,
   document.getElementById("crm")
);

ReactDOM.render(
   <HF.Footer /> ,
   document.getElementById("footer")
);
```

I did this so that i don't have to `import` header and footer on each page individually.

I have defined my routes in my content as

```
var routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={LoginBox}/>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard} />
    <Route path="/product" component={ProductLanding}/>
    <Route path="/salesfunnel" component={Salesfunnel}/>
    <Route path="/addmeeting" component={AddMeeting}/>
    <Route path="/pitchProduct" component={PitchProduct}/>
    <Route path="/mysubs" component={MySubs}/>
    <Route path="/updateproduct" component={UpdateProduct}/>
    <Route path="/transactionform" component={AddTransaction}/>
    <Route path="/sellerLanding" component={SellerLanding}/>
    <Route path="/addSeller" component={AddSeller}/>
  </Router>
)
```

Now some of my pages like dashboard, meeting are in header and when i want to open that page from header it is giving me this error:

> Links rendered outside of a router context cannot navigate.

Please help me what to do,
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using 3 `div's` and `rendering` different component, use a Homepage that will contain all the parts header, some route page and footer, like this:

```
export default HomePage extends React.Component{
    render(){
       return(
           <div>
               <Header/>
               {this.props.children}
               <Footer/>
           </div>
       )
    }
}
```

Make this `HomePage` as a main route and make `LoginBox` as a default route:

```
 var routes = (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={HomePage}>
            <IndexRoute component={LoginBox}/>
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashBoard} />
            <Route path="/product" component={ProductLanding}/>
            <Route path="/salesfunnel" component={Salesfunnel}/>
            <Route path="/addmeeting" component={AddMeeting}/>
            <Route path="/pitchProduct" component={PitchProduct}/>
            <Route path="/mysubs" component={MySubs}/>
            <Route path="/updateproduct" component={UpdateProduct}/>
            <Route path="/transactionform" component={AddTransaction}/>
            <Route path="/sellerLanding" component={SellerLanding}/>
            <Route path="/addSeller" component={AddSeller}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  routes,
  document.getElementById("crm")
);
```

If you write in this way then no need of using `ReactDOM.render` three times, no need of importing header and footer component on all the pages and it will be present on each page since each page will render inside `HomePage`. This will make you app structure more clear as well as if you want to put some more info on each page you can easily put that in `HomePage`.

Comment: Thanks brother.. Did it in just one shot ;) You are awesome :D

Comment: glad, to help you :)

Comment: One more question.. I have multiple div in my header and i want to hide one div on login page and show that div after successful login. Since header are defined in routes can i also do something to change some headers div property on different pages??

Comment: r u using redux/flux or any architecture?? if yes then maintain a bool in store whether user is loggedin of not and on the basis of that show the div in header component. Or you can do this by checking the url also in header comp by window.location, if url if logging the skip the rendering of that div :)

Comment: Wow.. Never thought of that. :P Thanks buddy.

Comment: Hey Mayank help me with one more thing please. ?

Comment: Its different from the above question..
I have a dropdown and text field and i want to change the text field value based on the drop down value.. I had tried that onChange of dropDown i will setState the text field's value but in that case it is not editable and i thought of giving defaultValue on place of value,but defaultValue only runs on first load.. How do i pre load the value of text field on selection of drop down?